# Dealing with CSV with a truncated quote

Tags: python, csv

So I have some data in a csv with delimiter=' ' and quotechar=' '. I'm using the python csv package to read it but here's the catch. There is one line that either has some text in a quote, or is just a single quote that is it looks either like this

```
...
"Some text"
...
```

or like this

```
...
"
...
```

Is there some way I can tell the reader to end quote if it hits a newline?

Comment: How about patching your broken input?

Comment: Its how the program outputs its data for some reason, its really stupid.

Comment: you can check the length of chars on newline...or check for equality with "" in which case you want to skip that line.

Comment: I meant is patching your broken input prior to parsing it an option?  If you just have one file of this kind I'd change it using an editor.  If you have a facility creating such a broken file, I'd write a patching tool (probably using `sed`).

Answer (score 0):

If the reader can handle such line catch it for instance:
Assume 10 Column

```
if len(csv_list) < 10:
    # Skip or repair Data
```